# CoreData: Private context with child Main context - FetchedResultsController not getting updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been trying to build a Core Data stack as described by [Marcus Zarra](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/), where he has a Private Queue context and a Main Queue context (where the Main Queue context is a child of the Private Queue context).

I believe I've correctly rebuilt ([here](https://github.com/iandundas/CoreDataCloudKitDemo/blob/a109914/CoreDataCloudKit/MCPersistenceController.swift)) his described `MCPersistenceController` faithfully in Swift (the example code was Obj-C).

The problem is in my [ListViewModel class](https://github.com/iandundas/CoreDataCloudKitDemo/blob/a10991496912f1d066016c5b63991cfa017415bd/CoreDataCloudKit/ListViewModel.swift) (which contains an `NSFetchedResultsController`). No matter what I try, its delegate callbacks (`controllerDidChangeContent` etc) don't get called when a new `Item` object is inserted.

- The FRC and NSFetchRequest use the Main Context; the item is inserted on the main context; the [save function](https://github.com/iandundas/CoreDataCloudKitDemo/blob/a109914/CoreDataCloudKit/MCPersistenceController.swift#L75) save the Main Context and then merge the changes into the Private Queue
- If I perform a manual `executeFetchRequest` on either context after inserting and saving, I do get the newly created `Item` back.
- If I listen for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notifications, they're indeed triggered after inserting.
- When I relaunch the app, my inserted `Item`s are now shown.

I can only assume it's an issue with doing something on the wrong thread and there being no reported error, but no matter what I've tried, when I insert a new `Item` the FRC triggers no delegate callback. Possibly it's some Swift thing that I've missed.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions at this point .

My simple proof-of-concept project (Swift 1.2) is on [GitHub](https://github.com/iandundas/CoreDataCloudKitDemo/tree/a109914/CoreDataCloudKit). (I didn't get to the CloudKit stuff yet..).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ListViewModel` object is a pure Swift object. The fetched results controller uses NSObject-descended functionality to check if the delegate responds to the delegate methods.

```
@objc
class ListViewModel: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
```

Fixes it.

Comment: that's it! Fantastic, thanks - god knows how long it would have taken me to find that.